# Maven: property substitution not done for /project/version tag of pom?

Tags: maven-2, properties, substitution, pom.xml

http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties says property "values are accessible anywhere within a POM".

Should this read "are accessible in *most* places within a POM"?

I can specify the version of a dependency no problem like so:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>${junit.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

But what about the version of the project itself like so:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" ...>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
    <version>${myversion}</version>

    <properties>
        <myversion>8</myversion>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>alpha</module>
        <module>beta</module>
    </modules>
    ...
```

If I try this <version> will not take the value 8. Here I've defined ${myversion} in the pom but the same seems to be the case if I specify -Dmyversion=8 on the command line.

If one of the modules specifies its parent with a hardcoded version number like so:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
    <version>8</version>
</parent>
```

When I try to build then when maven comes to look at the module's pom it will say it cannot find the given parent pom with version 8.

However if I hardcode version in the parent to 8 as well, rather than using ${myversion}, then everything works fine.

So it *seems* to me that property substitution does not happen for the /project/version tag of the parent pom.

Is this the case or is there some other explanation for what I seem to be seeing?

Regards,

/George

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Property substitution is not allowed in `/project/parent/(groupId|artifactId|version)` or in `/project/(groupId|artifactId|version)` by design in Maven 2.x.

So the rules are:

- hard code the version in the top `project/version` element.
- hard code the version in the `project/parent/version` element of children.
- children inherit the version unless they want to override it

  - there is thus not need for a `${myversion}` property
- use `${project.groupId}` and `${project.version}` for inter module dependencies.

You'll find an infinite number of threads on this topic on the maven user list (see for example [Pom Parent Version Properties](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Pom-Parent-Version-Properties-td124576.html)) and I'll just say that any attempt to workaround the above rules is wrong and doesn't work.

Version less `parent` will be allowed in Maven 3.1.

#### See also

- [MNG-624](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-624)

Comment: Nice succinct description of the rules. I'm glad you say versionless parent is coming in Maven 3.1. I can't really stomach the idea of hardcoding the version once per POM. It seems to work out ok, in both Maven 2 and 3, to "hardcode" the version in every pom (as version for top one, and as parent version for children) as a reference to a property defined in the top pom, but that's obviously hacky and Maven 3 complains.

Comment: Didn't make it to Maven 3.1 :(