# Using maven git describe plugin value as Jenkins build file name

Tags: maven, jenkins

I use the git-describe maven plugin to replace the POMs `<version>${describe}</version>` placeholder. `mvn deploy` needs a custom parameter passed in order for it to properly use the actual git describe value.

I'm now using Jenkins to build the project every time we push to the repo however it too doesn't properly use the actual git-describe value.

The jenkins build artifacts always end named `project-${describe}`

Are there any suggestions on ways I can customize the file names or force it to use the git-describe result? Otherwise I may be back to manual versioning...

Answer (score 1):

The version property does not allow variable substitution.  The first link I found googling this was [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684664/maven-property-substitution-not-done-for-project-version-tag-of-pom).

You'll have to use one of the versioning maven plugins.  The [maven release plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/) is the most popular, but you might find that the [versions maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) better meets your requirements.